# Sudo a2enmod rewrite no fount

Tags: apache

Good evening community.
I'm writing to see if you could help me with this little problem.
My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 and I need to activate Apache2's mod_rewrite. I have the xampp server running without problems but when I type the command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

it tells me that the command has not been found.
If you could shed light on me, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: `a2enmod` is for a proper Apache installation. For XAMPP you’ll need to use whatever tools they’re foisting upon people 

Comment: you just have to copy the mod_rewrite file into the mods enabled folder....that a2enmod is just creating a symbolic link in the mod enabled folder to the mod_rewrite file